# How to test Callback call in useEffect with React Hooks Testing Library

Tags: testing, hook, setstate, use-effect

I try to test a simple callback call in a useEffect hook:

```
export const useMyHook = (setState) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fakeFetch().then((val) => setState(val));
  }, [setState]);
};
```

I Want to verify the correct call of my setState, but I didn't find the way with react Hooks Testing Library. Whatever I try, the assertion fails.

`expect(setState).toBeCalled();`

You can find my code in a SandBox :

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-newton-nk85u

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, It's about React Hooks Testing library

Comment: Please put a [mre] *in the question* - what's the test setup? The outcome of that expectation?